# Want to change image source on area hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

want to load different image when hover any area of map.

```html
<img src="images/mapimg.png" usemap="#states" />
<map name="states">
  <area shape="poly" coords="4,349,121,416,111,205" title="test1">
  <area shape="poly" coords="226,287,234,255,132,231,129,402,151,404,150,429,362,465,362,385,283,359" title="test" />
</map>
```

Comment: explain a little more please ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of room for improvements, but basically like

```
 <img id="map" src="images/mapimg.png" usemap="#states" />
 <map name="states">
     <area style="background-color: black;" onmouseover="document.getElementById('map').src = 'other.png';" shape="poly" coords="4,349,121,416,111,205" title="test1">
     <area shape="poly" coords="226,287,234,255,132,231,129,402,151,404,150,429,362,465,362,385,283,359" title="test" />
 </map>
```

Comment: Thanxz for your help.